# Shipyard v2 for Docker fails to login

Tags: docker

I installed the docker v1.3.0
and latest shipyard v2.0.3
on Linux Mint 17
and modified `/etc/default/docker`

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Updated Firewall `/etc/default/ufw`

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

`sudo ufw allow 4243/tcp`

And I can access the Web UI on `http://localhost:8080/`

But for some or magically unknown reason I cannot login via the CLI

```
WiR3D@pc> /Data/Projects/docker-nginx-php $ sudo docker run --rm -it shipyard/shipyard-cli
shipyard cli> shipyard login
URL: http://localhost:8080
Username: admin
Password: shipyard
```

This is all I get:

```
FATA[0010] Post http://localhost:8080/auth/login: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --link shipyard:shipyard shipyard/shipyard-cli
echo "For login URL use: http://$SHIPYARD_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR:8080"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start the client as you did in a docker container this containers localhost points naturally on itself and no longer on the machine you started the container from.

You therefore need to provide the client with the (non-loopback) ip of your host.